# Continuity of $\textrm{argmin}$ set-valued mapping

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a finite set and $\Phi : X \mapsto 2^{X}$ be a set-valued mapping defined as follows:

$\Phi(y) := \underset{x \in X}{\textrm{argmin}} \; L(x, y)$.

I'm trying to figure out if, without any particular assumptions on $L: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$, $\Phi(\cdot)$ is continuous over the finite set $X$. I guess no - any hints or suggestions?

Comment: What would you have argmin do if there are multiple points $x$ for which $L$ attains the same (minimum) value for a given $y$? It seems natural to have $\Phi$ be a set-valued function, in which case you might not have a natural topology.

Comment: @BenW Thank you, I'm not really confident with discrete topology. To prove continuity I guess you should rely on the classic definition, right?

Comment: @or1426 Exactly, this is my point. You are right, $\Phi$ is a set-valued mapping and, for any given $y$, there may be more than one minimizer.

Comment: @or1426 Oh right, I didn't even realize that. So, I guess $2^X$ would have to be endowed with a topology, too. In this case, $\Phi$ might not be continuous after all given the trivial topology on $X$ (although it would always be continuous given the discrete topology on $X$).